# is it okay that some DC Adapter(connector) are not fully inside the device

Tags: electrical, power-supply

I have multiple monitors that their dc adapter (connectors) are not fully inside the device.
for example my monitor has a 180 ac to dc power. the final part when connecting the transformer to laptop(dc adapter(connector)) is not fully inside the device. Is this malfunctioned device or is it okay that some of the dc adapter(connector) is outside the device?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not about home improvement.

Answer (score 1):

It is OK if part of the connector is outside the device, especially if they are replacement adapters. Most of mine have 1/16 to 1/8 inch outside the device. Just make sure they are inserted in as far as possible. It's good to check with a flashlight inside the jack to make sure there's no debris if you feel the plug's not going in far enough.